# laravel redirecting to certain part of page

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5.6

I've got a long page where there is **comment box** at the very bottom just above **footer**.

When there is an error, it is shown just above the **comment box**. However, when I scroll down to comment box, I see errors after the page refreshes.

is there any way the can be done in `controller` (redirecting to certain part of page) to stay in the same position after **errors** are shown?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [HTML anchor links](https://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/link/html-anchor-link.html).

That way, you in your `controller` you can redirect your `users` to you url with *#comments* appended

Answer (score 1):

Like @Greg said and well, keep the routes and use the `anchors` to move them ot the correct place. Alternatively I would like to add that you can also make use of javascript to do a smooth scroll to the location you wish.

In some past projects I made use of `GET` variables on the url and `javascript` to detect them and scroll the user smoothly to the location. Basically the `GET` would be a `css class` or `id` in the `DOM` so the javascript knows where to scroll the user.

[JS smooth scroll](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_smooth_scroll.asp#section2)